# Preferences Screen on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-preferences

Where is this window on Android Studio? 
How we can add **Fragment Preferences** from this window on Android Studio?

This window on **Eclipse**.

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Comment: mm what is the problem on Drag Drop (it also good programming) ?! so ur answer there is no xml screen on Android Studio as Eclipse?  @ Gabe Sechan

Comment: I am also amazed after reading the question. I am using Android Studio since an year. But never thought of this screen :-P

Comment: what is the problem on this screen? @Paritosh mmmm :\

Comment: It frequently does things inefficiently, it leaves you unable to debug problems because you don't know what your layout is actually doing, and its actually slower most of the time.

Comment: yes Thanks @GabeSechan I just miss it when I turn to Android Stdio :)) :D

Answer (score 0):

This is called `Component Tree` in Android Studio.

To open this, follow the steps:

1. Open layout.xml file
2. Click on 'Design' Tab at bottom
3. Select 'Component Tree' from right corner (See image)

[image: Component Tree]

Best luck!

Comment: mm this for xml files located on res\layout !! But what I need the files located on res\xml which are for Preferences!  mmm